# Display code (HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, jQuery, etc.) on a webpage, just like code is displayed here, in a box, syntax-highlighted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'd like to display code on a web page. However I'd like it to keep its spacing *and* be color coded by syntax.

**Please do not respond with:**

1. Replacing the < > & " with entities such as `&lt;` This is not what I need: doing this removes all my line breaks and my spacing and provides no color
2. `<pre> <code>` This totally fails it still tries to execute the HTML and PHP

See if I copy and paste code into here. It gives me *exactly* what I want on my site nicely color coded and with the white space maintained.

```
                    <span style="color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://stackapps.com">api/apps</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://careers.stackoverflow.com">careers</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#E8272C;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://serverfault.com">serverfault.com</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#00AFEF;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://superuser.com">superuser.com</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#969696;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com">meta</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#46937D;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com">area&nbsp;51</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#C0D0DC;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://webapps.stackexchange.com">webapps</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://gaming.stackexchange.com">gaming</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#dd4814;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://askubuntu.com">ubuntu</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#9ce4fe;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://webmasters.stackexchange.com">webmasters</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#cf4d3f;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://cooking.stackexchange.com">cooking</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#f4f28d;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://gamedev.stackexchange.com">game development</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#0f3559;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://math.stackexchange.com">math</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#f2f2f2;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://photo.stackexchange.com">photography</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#037187;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://stats.stackexchange.com">stats</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#f1e7cc;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://tex.stackexchange.com">tex</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#e1cdae;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://english.stackexchange.com">english</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#a2d9f6;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://cstheory.stackexchange.com">theoretical cs</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#1b3e6c;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://programmers.stackexchange.com">programmers</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#293a5d;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://unix.stackexchange.com">unix</a>&nbsp;

                    <span style="color:#bec0cb;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://apple.stackexchange.com">apple</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#939185;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com">wordpress</a>
```

I'm looking for a way to display code (without it executing) and have the color coded syntax just like this website does, or like [TextWrangler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBEdit#TextWrangler) (the text editor) does. Often this will be the code of the whole page from doc type to `html`.

I've seen color coded display of code on many developer websites, so I know it's doable, but any Google Search ends up bringing me to the billion pages on how to change font color and such in HTML.

I need this to work for PHP HTML at a *minimum* and preferably CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery as well.

PS: the color coded syntax is not necessary, but keeping my format (line breaks spacing white space, etc.) is absolutely necessary and with the amount of code it posts, it is not feasible to do so manually.

Comment: Have you tried Firebugging the highlighted code in your question?

Answer (score 9):

I use the [syntax highlighter from Alex Gorbatchev](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) (JavaScript).

See http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html for instructions. But if you need to support displaying HTML containing script elements, you'll need to fall back to the `<pre>` method, and thus escape `<`, `>` and `&`.

Comment: Both links are (effectively) broken (both redirect to `https://gogopdf.com/en/blog/Alex-Gorbatchev-And-gogopdf-Turn-Raw-Javascript-To-A-PDF-Service`). A malicious site?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to do:

1. Replace `< > & "` with entities such as `&lt;` You do this, then do #2 to preserve spacing. You cannot avoid escaping entities since those characters can cause invalid HTML which causes parsing errors in the browser.
2. Use `<pre><code>` to preserve spacing. After you escaped those special characters,  and  will not cause the escaped HTML and PHP to get executed (unless you explicitly told PHP and HTML to execute them).

Syntax coloring is a bit more difficult, since you will need a parser that understands the language you're trying to show; even Stack Overflow's syntax coloring does not always work as well as it could.

Answer (score 1):

Look at PHP's built-in [highlight_string()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) and [highlight_file()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SyntaxHighlighter.

[Download](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/download/) SyntaxHighlighter.

The SyntaxHighlighter plugin is also available for WordPress users.

For details, read [this post](http://blog.klassicweb.com/how-to-display-any-programming-code-on-a-webpage/).

Comment: Your post, linking from the word "this" is a 404 not found.

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken (redirects to `https://gogopdf.com/en/blog/Alex-Gorbatchev-And-gogopdf-Turn-Raw-Javascript-To-A-PDF-Service`). A malicious site?

Comment: The second link is also broken: "*Server Not Found*. Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at blog.klassicweb.com."