# How to display code blocks in my private blog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to display code blocks in my private blogging site. I am creating it from the scratch.
How to proceed with it. I am totally confused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028764/display-code-html-css-php-javascript-jquery-etc-on-a-webpage-just-like-code-i

Comment: I tried tinyMCE. But it does not have such a functionality, and i could not find a plugin for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the proper markup to make the code monospaced and keep whitespace as-is. This basically means using `<pre>` and `<code>`:

```
<pre><code>
your();
code = "here";
</code></pre>
```

After that you just need to add some nice CSS styling to make it look nice. And if you want syntax highlighting like here on Stack Overflow simply the easiest way to get it is adding google's prettify: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: Thanks..But I want to display the code like this site: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

I need color highlighting and indentation as well.

Comment: Did you actually *read* my answer? Indentation is done by yourself and preserved by using `<pre>` tags. For highlighting I've linked you to something that's even used here on SO.

Comment: ya it got updated after i posted the comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). Its easy and looks really good.
**[Demo Link](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/)**

Comment: Ya i looked at it. Its nice alternative. Thanks :)